# iOS 7: Unzipping zip files, natively

Tags: ios, zip

I'm working on an iPad app and I need to be able to download and unzip a collection of images to display. Is this possible to do natively in iOS 7? iOS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to use third-party tools like [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) or [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list) in order to work with zip files.

Using SSZipArchive, the line below would unzip a zip file:

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

**Edit:**

It turns out that in iOS 7, Apple added support to natively unzip files in iMessage and in the Mail app! Not sure if this is 100% related, but it might help. See [this link](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/10/ios-7-supports-zip-files.html) for more info.

Comment: I should be more specific, I need a library to do this in my app. I guess I can go with ZipArchive...

Comment: Oh, sorry I guess I misread the question. Why are you hesitant to use ZipArchive?

Comment: The app is for work, and one of our mandates is to use as few third party tools as possible.

Comment: Just a heads up, the link to SSZipArchive you provided is not to the latest version - use this instead https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Comment: @ecnepsnai You're right! Looked like I linked to a fork by accident. I've updated the answer with the correct link. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to change the extracted file name?